# Por que meu código está dando undefined?

Tags: javascript

Toda vez que tento rodar esse código o resultado é sempre `undefined`. Me expliquem os erros desse código e também me ajudem também com a possível solução. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
let tipo1 = prompt('')
let tipo2 = prompt('')
let tipo3 = prompt('')


let animais = ['aguia', 'pomba', 'homem', 'vaca', 'pulga', 'lagarta', 'sanguessuga', 'minhoca']
let tipo = ['vertebrado', 'ave', 'carnivoro', 'onivoro', 'mamifero', 'herbivoro', 'hematofago', 'invertebrado', 'inseto', 'anelideo']


//aguia
if (tipo1 == tipo[0] || tipo1 == tipo[1] || tipo1 == tipo[2]) {
    if (tipo2 == tipo[0] || tipo2 == tipo[1] || tipo2 == tipo[2]) {
        if (tipo3 == tipo[0] || tipo3 == tipo[1] || tipo3 == tipo[2]) {
            alert(animais[0])
        }
    }
}

//pomba
else if (tipo1 == tipo[0] || tipo1 == tipo[1] || tipo1 == tipo[3]) {
    if (tipo2 == tipo[0] || tipo2 == tipo[1] || tipo2 == tipo[3]) {
        if (tipo3 == tipo[0] || tipo3 == tipo[1] || tipo3 == tipo[3]) {
            alert(animais[1])
        }
    }
}

//homem 
else if (tipo1 == tipo[1] || tipo1 == tipo[3] || tipo1 == tipo[4]) {
    if (tipo2 == tipo[1] || tipo2 == tipo[3] || tipo2 == tipo[4]) {
        if (tipo3 == tipo[1] || tipo3 == tipo[3] || tipo3 == tipo[4]) {
            alert(animais[2])
        }
    }
}

//vaca
else if (tipo1 == tipo[1] || tipo1 == tipo[3] || tipo1 == tipo[5]) {
    if (tipo2 == tipo[1] || tipo2 == tipo[3] || tipo2 == tipo[5]) {
        if (tipo3 == tipo[1] || tipo3 == tipo[3] || tipo3 == tipo[5]) {
            alert(animais[3])
        }
    }
}

//pulga
else if (tipo1 == tipo[6] || tipo1 == tipo[7] || tipo1 == tipo[8]) {
    if (tipo2 == tipo[6] || tipo2 == tipo[7] || tipo2 == tipo[8]) {
        if (tipo3 == tipo[6] || tipo3 == tipo[7] || tipo3 == tipo[8]) {
            alert(animais[4])
        }
    }
}

//lagarta
else if (tipo1 == tipo[7] || tipo1 == tipo[5] || tipo1 == tipo[8]) {
    if (tipo2 == tipo[7] || tipo2 == tipo[5] || tipo2 == tipo[8]) {
        if (tipo3 == tipo[7] || tipo3 == tipo[5] || tipo3 == tipo[8]) {
            alert(animais[5])
        }
    }
}

//sanguessuga
else if (tipo1 == tipo[7] || tipo1 == tipo[9] || tipo1 == tipo[6]) {
    if (tipo2 == tipo[7] || tipo2 == tipo[9] || tipo2 == tipo[6]) {
        if (tipo3 == tipo[7] || tipo3 == tipo[9] || tipo3 == tipo[6]) {
            alert(animais[6])
        }
    }
}

//minhoca
else if (tipo1 == tipo[7] || tipo1 == tipo[9] || tipo1 == tipo[3]) {
    if (tipo2 == tipo[7] || tipo2 == tipo[9] || tipo2 == tipo[3]) {
        if (tipo3 == tipo[7] || tipo3 == tipo[9] || tipo3 == tipo[3]) {
            alert(animais[7])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não resolva o problema dessa forma, você vai ficar louco tentando encontrar todas as combinações. Existem maneiras bem mais fáceis, por exemplo [BST](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_bin%C3%A1ria_de_busca). Eu sugiro que crie uma nova pergunta mostrando reapresentando o problema, mostrando a forma que está fazendo e perguntando se há maneiras mais fáceis de abordagem a esse tipo de problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rodando seu código, não obtive o erro informado.

De qualquer forma, você está complicando o código à toa. Um dos erros foi colocar todas as classificações em um mesmo array, e com isso você se perdeu nas várias combinações possíveis de serem testadas.

Mas na verdade as informações seguem uma hierarquia, então uma forma de organizá-las seria:

```js
let classificacao = {
    'vertebrado': {
        'ave': {
            'carnívoro': 'águia',
            'onívoro': 'pomba'
        },
        'mamífero': {
            'onívoro': 'homem',
            'herbívoro': 'vaca'
        }
    },
    'invertebrado': {
        'inseto': {
            'hematófago': 'pulga',
            'herbívoro': 'lagarta'
        },
        'anelídeo': {
            'hematófago': 'sanguessuga',
            'onívoro': 'minhoca'
        }
    }
};
let filo = prompt(`Filo (${Object.keys(classificacao).join(', ')})`);
if (classificacao[filo]) {
    let classe = prompt(`Classe (${Object.keys(classificacao[filo]).join(', ')})`);
    if (classificacao[filo][classe]) {
        let alimentacao = prompt(`Tipo de alimentação (${Object.keys(classificacao[filo][classe]).join(', ')})`);
        if (classificacao[filo][classe][alimentacao]) {
            alert(`Animal encontrado: ${classificacao[filo][classe][alimentacao]}`);
        } else {
            alert('Não foi encontrado nenhum animal com essas características');
        }
    } else {
        alert(`Opção inválida: ${classe}`);
    }
} else {
    alert(`Opção inválida: ${filo}`);
}
```

Ou seja, o objeto `classificacao` tem 2 chaves, "vertebrado" e "invertebrado". Cada uma delas, por sua vez, tem as respectivas classes de animais (que por sua vez, possui cada animal de acordo com sua alimentação).

Sendo assim, eu vou lendo os dados um a um, verificando se existe a referida classificação e só prossigo caso exista. Se não existir, já mostro uma mensagem de erro e nem leio as outras informações.

Também coloquei no texto do `prompt` as opções existentes, para facilitar para o usuário (assim ele sabe as opções disponíveis para digitar).

Answer (score -2):

Tecnicamente ele rodou. Como você tem um if else contínuo se ele tem qualquer tipo de aguia ele entrará no if, não executando os demais else if.

Exemplo:

```
    tipo1 = 'vertebrado'
        tipo2 = 'mamifero'
        tipo3 = 'herbivoro'
     //como tipo1 == tipo[0] retorna true, ele executa o bloco 
        if (tipo1 == tipo[0] || tipo1 == tipo[1] || tipo1 == tipo[2]) {
//como tipo2 == tipo[0] || tipo2 == tipo[1] || tipo2 == tipo[2] retorna false, ele para de executar aqui
            if (tipo2 == tipo[0] || tipo2 == tipo[1] || tipo2 == tipo[2]) {
                if (tipo3 == tipo[0] || tipo3 == tipo[1] || tipo3 == tipo[2]) {
                    alert(animais[0])
                }
            }
        }

//mas como ele executou o bloco do if, ele não testará os demais animais
        //pomba
        else if
```

Para resolver isso, teste cada coisa de uma vez ['vertebrado', 'invertebrado'], ['ave','mamifero','inseto','anelideo'] e ['carnivoro', 'onivoro', 'herbivero', 'hematofago']

Além disso sugiro usar uma função e switch para um código mais limpo.

Comment: Outro problema do seu código é que se ele não lida com tipos repetidos. Teste tipo1 = tipo2 = tipo3 = 'vertebrado'

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu só não entendi muito quando vc colocou ['vertebrado', 'invertebrado'], ['ave','mamifero','inseto','anelideo'] e ['carnivoro', 'onivoro', 'herbivero', 'hematofago']

Comment: É que acho melhor fazer a seleção por etapas

Primeira etapa
['vertebrado', 'invertebrado']
Segunda etapa
['ave','mamifero','inseto','anelideo']
Terceira etapa
['carnivoro', 'onivoro', 'herbivero', 'hematofago']

Com as três tipagens feitas, você é capaz de determinar o animal